# Microsoft GDK GameInput C# Calls in .Net 6 - Modern Controller Input

Tags: c#, .net, windows, uwp, game-development

Microsoft GameInput is an API that is part of the Microsoft Game Development Kit (GDK) first released in 2021-06-24 [June 2021 GDK Public Release](https://github.com/microsoft/GDK/releases/tag/June_2021)

The most recent release is the [June 2022 Release](https://github.com/microsoft/GDK/releases/tag/June_2022_Update_1)

GameInput is the API that exposes input devices and is used to build interactivity.

[Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/gdk/_content/gc/input/overviews/input-overview) says (Under Getting Started):

> GameInput is the recommended API for all new code, regardless of the target platform, because it provides support across all Microsoft platforms (including earlier versions of Windows), and provides superior performance versus legacy APIs.

And also says:

> GameInput is available on all Windows platforms—PC, Xbox, HoloLens, IoT, and others—and is callable from GDK, Win32, and Universal Windows Platform (UWP) applications. Most importantly, it's available on earlier versions of Windows all the way back to Windows 7 via a redistributable installer package. This enables a single input codebase to be used across the entire Microsoft ecosystem, with no platform/version special-casing required.

Which all sounds very impressive indeed.

But I am a C# developer, looking to port an older application from .Net Framework v 4.5.2 which has been out of support for [several months now](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-framework-4-5-2-4-6-4-6-1-will-reach-end-of-support-on-april-26-2022/).

> .NET Framework 4.5.2, 4.6, and 4.6.1 will reach end of support* on April 26, 2022. After this date, we will no longer provide updates including security fixes or technical support for these versions.

Previously using [SharpDX.XInput](http://sharpdx.org/wiki/class-library-api/xinput/) that was last updated [2018-08-24](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpDX.XInput), migrating away from SharpDX.XInput is also on the cards too.

Given that Microsoft is recommending GameInput as the API set for all new code regardless of the target platform, is it reasonable to expect in the foreseeable future that there will be official C# bindings for the GameInput API set, in particular for Windows Server which our current application is expected to support.

Alternatives to GameInput is the [Windows.Gaming.Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Gaming.Input?view=winrt-10240) namespace of APIs, which look similar but are also different, and part of the UWP/WinRT suite of functions. That said, XInput isn't being deprecated at least yet, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/xinput/xinput-versions) for XInput Versions says that XInput v1.4 is shipped with Windows 10 directly, and inspecting the SharpDX source reveals that it first tries v1.4 via LoadLibrary (Link omitted, lack of reputation to post more), if failing falling back to v1.3 and if that fails, falling back to v9.1.0

For C# developers doing new code-work is there an expectation of bindings to GameInput being provided, or are we to utilize Windows.Gaming.Input or XInput instead through interop?

For us, it's imperative that the software work on Windows Server 2019 and up, and Windows 10 IoT 2019 LTSC (v1809) and up. Dropping support for Windows 7 is also on the to-do list as part of the upgrade from the older framework which is why we were using it for so long.

Answer (score 0):

PInvoking XInput 1.4 is what I use in my .Net FX code. Its not perfect (vibration support is 360-controller style) but works well enough for most use-cases.

Comment: I was hoping to use GDK/GameInput because that supports all kinds of input devices, not just standard Gamepads. : /
If I use XInput then I'm locked into only standard Gamepads.